# Problem with reseting openKeys in Ant Design Menu within Sider

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have antd Menu inside collapsible Sider. I've set default open keys for one of Submenus and they should open one at a time. Here is my code for the Menu:

```
const MainMenu = ({ defaultOpenKeys }) => {
  const [openKeys, setOpenKeys] = useState(defaultOpenKeys);
  const rootKeys = ["sub1", "sub2"];
  // Open only one submenu at a time
  const onOpenChange = props => {
    const latestOpenKey = props.find(key => openKeys.indexOf(key) === -1);
    if (rootKeys.indexOf(latestOpenKey) === -1) {
      setOpenKeys(props);
    } else {
      setOpenKeys(latestOpenKey ? [latestOpenKey] : defaultOpenKeys);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Menu
      theme="dark"
      openKeys={openKeys}
      defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
      mode="inline"
      onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
    >
      <Menu.Item key="1">
        Option 1
      </Menu.Item>
      <SubMenu key="sub1" title="User">
        <Menu.Item key="2">Tom</Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
      <SubMenu key="sub2" title="Team">
        <Menu.Item key="3">Team 1</Menu.Item>
      </SubMenu>
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default MainMenu;
```

I pass `defaultOpenKeys` from the Sider.

```
const SiderDemo = () => {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const toggleSider = () => {
    setCollapsed(!collapsed);
  };
  return (
    <Layout style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={toggleSider}>
        {React.createElement(
          collapsed ? MenuFoldOutlined : MenuUnfoldOutlined
        )}
      </Button>
      <Sider
        collapsible
        collapsed={collapsed}
        collapsedWidth={0}
        trigger={null}
      >
        <Menu defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]} />
      </Sider>
      ...
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

It works on mount, but when I collapse the Sider, `defaultOpenKeys` are being reset. How can I keep `defaultOpenKeys` from being reset, when the Sider is collapsed?

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sider-demo-nbc43?file=/index.js:698-713) and added console log in the Menu. You can see that `defaultOpenKeys` and `openKeys` are the same on mount. When I collapse the Sider, the console log is triggered twice. The first time `defaultOpenKeys` and `openKeys` are the same. And the second time `openKeys` become empty. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason:** on closing the sidebar it is closing  opened sidemenu so it gonna trigger openchange with empty array and hence your logic making it reset to empty.

**Here is code sandbox link with updated code**

https://codesandbox.io/s/sider-demo-0der5?file=/Menu.jsx

**Suggestion:** Its anti pattern to assign props to initial state. if prop value changed in parent component then  the new prop value will never be displayed because intial state  will never update the current state of the component. The initialization of state from props only runs when the component is first created

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great. Concerning your suggestion, do you mean the `defaultOpenKeys` passed to the Menu? How should I do it then? The `defaultOpenKeys` can change only navigating to a new page.

Comment: Checked it once again, now the submenu can't be closed. It closes only on open of another submenu item.

Comment: updated my answer based on your comments, please have a look

Comment: without useeffect it can be solved using if condition with !collapsed.. but in future if you remove 0 width and want collapsed menu then it doesn't gonna work.. so made changes to work for all the conditions (took care about anti pattern too)

Comment: Thank you very much, but now the default submenu is always open, when I open the menu. Even if I've opened another submenu before close. I need the default submenu to be open only until the user has clicked  another submenu. So basically default submenu (or current submenu clicked by the user) should stay open irrespectively of the collapsed state of the menu. But if the user has selected another submenu, it should be open instead the default one.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sider-demo-xigq5?file=/Menu.jsx